# Is the Veronese embedding rigid?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider the Veronese embedding $v:\mathbb{CP}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{CP}^N$ where $$(z_0:z_1:\ldots:z_n)\mapsto(z_0^d:z_0^{d-1}z_2:\ldots:z_n^d),$$
and both projective spaces are equipped with the corresponding Fubini-Study metrics.

I read that this is an isometric embedding. Is it also rigid? That is, if $k:\mathbb{CP}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{CP}^N$ is another embedding, does there exist an isometry $U$ of $\mathbb{CP}^N$ such that $U\circ k=v$ ?

Any help, suggestion or reference would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've stated it, not even close. For example, you could embed $\Bbb P^n$ *linearly* or with lower degree into a $\Bbb P^M\subset\Bbb P^N$. If you require that the embedding be nondegenerate (i.e., that its image lie in no hyperplane), then your result seems plausible. But it's still not correct unless the degree is minimal. For example, any two rational curves of degree $3$ in $\Bbb P^3$ are projectively equivalent, but two smooth rational curves of degree $4$ in $\Bbb P^3$ need not be. And certainly what you asked can only have a hope if the degrees are the same (consider the hyperplane class in $\Bbb P^N$ restricted to the respective embeddings of $\Bbb P^n$).

Comment: Thank you Ted, I have been thinking about it. What came to my mind is the Calabi rigitidy theorem and that the veronese embedding is isometric and holomorphic.

Comment: I guess, If we also assume that is also full (not contained in any hyperplane) this should give that this isometric holomorphic immersion is "equivalent" to any other isometric immersion.

Comment: Well, if you make them both isometric embeddings with the same metric on the domain, then that will fix the degree. But, as I indicated, even embeddings of $\Bbb P^1$ of the same degree needn't be projectively (or unitarily) equivalent. It's true, I believe, if the degree is minimal (i.e., what's given by the Veronese), but I haven't worked out a proof for general $n$.